# Php, нужна помощь с массивом

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте. Я получаю массив такого вида:

```
 Array
  (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [dt] => 1523728800
        [main] => Array
            (
                [temp] => 16.84
                [temp_min] => 15.73
                [temp_max] => 16.84
                [pressure] => 1001.67
                [sea_level] => 1036.08
                [grnd_level] => 1001.67
                [humidity] => 66
                [temp_kf] => 1.11
            )

        [weather] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 800
                        [main] => Clear
                        [description] => clear sky
                        [icon] => 01n
                    )

            )


        [dt_txt] => 2018-04-14 18:00:00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [dt] => 1523739600
        [main] => Array
            (
                [temp] => 12.97
                [temp_min] => 12.23
                [temp_max] => 12.97
                [pressure] => 1002.14
                [sea_level] => 1036.93
                [grnd_level] => 1002.14
                [humidity] => 67
                [temp_kf] => 0.74
            )

        [weather] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 800
                        [main] => Clear
                        [description] => clear sky
                        [icon] => 01n
                    )

            )

        [dt_txt] => 2018-04-14 21:00:00
    )
```

И таких ещё 36. По 8 массивов с погодой на каждый день с шагом в 3 часа. Как мне выбрать массивы с погодой именно на сегодняшнюю дату? Как видите, дата возвращается - `dt_txt`, но как мне правильно провести по ней поиск?

Comment: идем в цикле по всем элементам и проверяем что strpos($a['dt_txt'], date('Y-m-d')) !== false   - это нужные нам элементы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удобнее по dt проверить. Пройдитесь в цикле по массиву:

```
foreach ($array AS $key => $value) {
   $dt = (int) $value['dt'];
   if ($dt >= (time() - 86400)) {
      // Это сегодняшняя погода
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Исходный массив:

```
$array = [
    [
        'dt' => 1523728800,
        'main' => [
                'temp' => 16.84
            ],
        'weather' =>
            [
                [
                    'id' => 800,
                    'main' => 'Clear'
                ]
            ],
        'dt_txt' => '2018-04-14 18:00:00'
    ],
    [
        'dt' => 1523728800,
        'main' => [
                'temp' => 16.84
            ],
        'weather' =>
            [
                [
                    'id' => 800,
                    'main' => 'Clear'
                ]
            ],
        'dt_txt' => '2018-04-14 18:00:00'
    ],
    [
        'dt' => 1523728800,
        'main' => [
                'temp' => 16.84
            ],
        'weather' =>
            [
                [
                    'id' => 800,
                    'main' => 'Clear'
                ]
            ],
        'dt_txt' => '2018-04-15 18:00:00'
    ]
];
```

Перебрать и сделать новый массив с ключами по дате через [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php).

```
$weather = [];
array_walk($array, function($item) use (&$weather){
    $dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($item['dt_txt']));
    $weather[$dt][] = $item;
});

$current_date = date('Y-m-d');

var_dump($weather[$current_date]);
```

Либо фильтровать исходный массив через [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php).

```
$res = array_filter($array, function($item){
    $date = explode(' ', $item['dt_txt']);
    if(strtotime($date[0]) == strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))){
        return $item;
    }
});

var_dump($res);
```